# Circle drawing problems (JFreeChart )

Tags: java, geometry, drawing, drawellipse

Please help me to solve 2 problems with drawing a circle:

**1)** I want to make a perfect circle.
Width == Height but it still draws an ellipse:

[image: generated image]

If you try to rotate this image you'll see what i mean:

[image: rotated image]

**How can i get a perfect circle?**

**2)** Image size: 300x300 px. Distances between edges of image and circle are different:

Top: 9 px.
Bottom: 8 px.
Left: 11 px.
Right: 12 px.

I want to get same distances betwen every edge and circle for example:
Top == Bottom ==  Left == Right == 10 px.

**How can i do this?**

Here is my code:

```
public Circle(String title) 
{
chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(""/*title*/, "", "", new XYSeriesCollection());

chart.setBorderVisible(false);
chart.removeLegend();

XYPlot plot = ((XYPlot)chart.getPlot());

plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
plot.setOutlineVisible(false);

double range = 1.45f;

plot.getRangeAxis().setRange(-range, range);
plot.getRangeAxis().setTickLabelsVisible(false);
plot.getRangeAxis().setTickMarksVisible(false);
plot.getRangeAxis().setAxisLineVisible(false);
plot.getRangeAxis().setLowerMargin(0.0f);
plot.getRangeAxis().setUpperMargin(0.0f);

plot.getDomainAxis().setRange(-range, range);
plot.getDomainAxis().setTickLabelsVisible(false);
plot.getDomainAxis().setTickMarksVisible(false);
plot.getDomainAxis().setAxisLineVisible(false);
plot.getDomainAxis().setLowerMargin(0.0f);
plot.getDomainAxis().setUpperMargin(0.0f);

double outRad = range - 0.01f;

Ellipse2D outercircle = new Ellipse2D.Double(0.0f - outRad, 0.0f - outRad, outRad * 2.0f, outRad * 2.0f);

plot.addAnnotation(new XYShapeAnnotation(outercircle, new BasicStroke(2.0f), Color.BLACK));
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could be an issue with using such a small number. What happens if you use a bigger range, say `145f` instead of `1.45f`.

Comment: 145F - same result